# Moringa tree has yellow leaves

Tags: diagnosis

My Moringa tree is in a pot, it's about 3 ft' tall, leaves keep getting yellow and fall off.  I read that Epsom salt is good and coffee. Any suggestions?  It gets full sun in New Orleans.

Comment: A photo of both the tree and its pot would be helpful, but how log has the tree been in the same pot?

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to upload a picture.  It has been it it's present pot coming on a year I think.